# DataAnnotations [Required]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validación

Tengo este ViewModel:

```
public class ActividadViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar el tipo de actividad")]
    [Display(Name = "Actividad")]
    public string TipoActividad { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar el estado")]
    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string Confirma { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar las actividades a realizar")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Actividades a Realizar /Solicitudes /Información del Problema")]
    public string Activi { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la fecha inicial")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha Inicio")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime VFechaInicio { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar la fecha final")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha Fin")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime VFechaTermino { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar las actividades realizadas")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Actividades Realizadas")]
    public string Activi_Realiza { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar el contacto")]
    [Display(Name = "Contacto")]
    public string ContactoID { get; set; }
}
```

y cuando creo el formulario lo hago con los helpers de html para los campos requeridos

```
asp-validation-for="Activi"
```

pero al momento de comprobar en el formulario no me aparece el mensaje de error, simplemente me pasa el modelo invalido.

¿saben que hace falta?

Answer (score 1):

Será que te falta agregar las librerías de validación de jquery? Lo puedes hacer incluyendo la siguientes linea de código en tus vistas:

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```